# How to change resource string when going from test to production in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I use Google Play to deploy an app. For alpha-testers, I use a test server, while beta and production, I use a production server. It would be great if I in the code would  know if the APK is in alpha testing, beta testing or production in Google Play. Then I wouldn't need to upload a new APK to Google Play when the APK is going from test to production.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible because google just control who will access the app (and not make anything different). Maybe, you can add a flag in you server: like: currentReleasedVersion=1.1.1. So, the app check this flag and if the value is different, it uses the test server... if the value matches, app can use the production server... Then, you increment server flag as soon as you release new versions... Just an idea..